# Infinite loop when attempting to list files

Tags: linux, files, ls

There is a particular directory that I am working with that has about 50,000 files in it. When I try to list the contents using `ls -f -1` is generates a list that repeats forever. Here are a couple of other commands I've tried that don't work at all:

```
Command  Result
-------  ---------------
find     "killed"
updatedb "updatedb: memory exhausted"
```

I even wrote a python script to list the files, but it didn't work either.

This problem directory is a Windows file share, so maybe that is part of the problem. When I list the contents in Windows, it does fine. When I use Windows powershell to copy the contents of the directory into a new directory and then try to list the contents on my Linux (RHEL) system, it works fine.

Lastly, in Windows, I compared the contents of original directory that was giving me problems with the new directory I just created. I did this by listing in windows powershell with the command 'dir -Force', to include hidden files. I diff'ed the two files and they were exactly the same.

Comment: What type of share?: How is it being shared?

Comment: What do you mean, "_it repeats forever_"? Listing 50000 files will take quite a time; are you really sure you're seeing the same set of files repeated? (That would be exceedingly unusual.)

Comment: What did you try with `find`? Did you had the `-P` flag so that it does not follow symlinks...

Comment: I don't know what type of windows share. I'd have to ask around. It's repeating the same 4096 files over and over. When I try 'find -P', it runs for 10-20 seconds and then reports, "Killed".

Comment: I ssh'ed into a a Solaris computer and was able to list the files just fine for the problem directory. This is truly baffling why Solaris works, but Linux does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a CIFS mount instead of NFS and this solved the problem! Linux doesn't like to talk to Windows via the NFS mount.